# replace escaped quotes with single quotes bash, sed

Tags: bash, macos, sed, tr

I'm trying to prepare some data to dump into a psql database.

The problem I'm running into is that my data contains escaped double quotes. I need to replace the `\"` with `'` .

So I need to change:

`\"show the cash pool history\"`

into:

`'show the cash pool history'`

When I try to parse the JSON into postgres, it chokes when it gets to "\ .

I'm simply trying to use a tool in bash (like sed or tr) to remove the `\"` and replace with single quotes.

I've been at this for hours. No luck, please help!!

Comment: You mention JSON; is this real, proper JSON that a JSON parser would understand? `jq` may be the right tool to use. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Apostrophes are not legal quotation marks in JSON; are you sure you're approaching this right?  If you have a JSON column in PostgreSQL, then I believe the entire JSON document goes in single quotes, like a normal SQL string. But it shouldn't contain any, other than apostrophes inside double-quoted string values...

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is capable of handling this, you just need to be careful with your quoting. I'm assuming here that your file is stored in `b.txt`, but `cat b.txt` can be replaced with any command.

```
$ cat b.txt | sed -e 's/\\"/'\''/g'
```

The expression is three strings concatenated `s/\\"/`, `'`, and `/g`. The middle one is represented as `\'`, and the other two are single-quoted.

```
$ cat b.txt | sed -e "s/\\\\\"/'/g"
```

will also work, but is somewhat less readable.

```
$ cat b.txt
\"show the cash pool history\"
```

and the output is

```
'show the cash pool history'
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative (GNU `sed`)

```
sed 's/\\"/\x27/g' text
```

Comment: Oh he's bringing out the voodoo hex!

Comment: easier than octal notation! Otherwise you have to do the sacred ritual of escaping the quotes...

Comment: I won't argue with that... hex is my preference usually, but I'm not feeling myself lately. nice simple answer +1

Comment: That's shorter, but note that the question is tagged [tag:osx]; macOS `sed` doesn't support `\x`-prefixed hex. escape sequences (or any escape sequences at all (other than backreferences) in the replacement string, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` or `tr` perhaps as an alternative to `sed`:

```
echo '\"show the cash pool history\"' # \"show the cash pool history\"
```

**awk**

```
awk '{ gsub(/\\"/, "\047"); print }'
```

Using octal values can be helpful in tricky situations (047 is the single-quote).

**tr**

```
tr -s '\\"' \'
```

This uses a simple approach, similar to the `awk` example, with the `-s` option (*squeeze*) — which replaces each instance of a sequence of repeated characters listed in set 1 with a single instance of the character specified in set 2.

**Result**:

```
'show the cash pool history'
```

Comment: The `awk` command works, but the `tr` command is brittle, because it'll translate any stand-alone `\ ` and `"` instances as well (`tr` never matches multi-character sequences as such). As an aside: using  `\' ` is simpler than `'\047'`.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for the comments; you're definitely correct, as `tr` isn't the most versatile, although it might not be too bad for certain scenarios; yes \' is simpler, but I was actually showing that octal values can be used as well ( in hindsight once was enough i think too ) - good suggestions, much appreciated.